# LINQ to sql subquery with 2 tables

Tags: c#, sql, database, linq

I need do in c# this sql query

```
select a.Codigo,c.Capacidad,c.Dia,c.jefe
from Autonomo a, Centro c
where a.Codigo_Centro=c.Codigo and a.Codigo_PC=1022;
```

How can I do it with LINQ to sql? Thanks!

Comment: Use a Join statement : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
var resultado =  
    from a in Autonomo 
    join c in Centro on a.Codigo_Centro equals c.Codigo 
    select new { a.Codigo,c.Capacidad,c.Dia,c.jefe};
```

To print:

```
foreach (var item in resultado) 
{  
    Console.WriteLine(item.Codigo + ", " + item.Capacidad);   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just FYI other answer is missing where clause.don't forget where clause

```
var query =  from a in Autonomo 
             join c in Centro 
             on a.Codigo_Centro equals c.Codigo
             where a.Codigo_PC == 1022
             select new { a.Codigo,c.Capacidad,c.Dia,c.jefe};
```

Comment: yes, I knew. I only had a problem with the "join". Thanks for your reply my friend!